# Baryons annihilation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics, resource-recommendations, scattering-cross-section, baryons

I was wondering if there is a way of calculate the annihilation cross section for two baryons, say $p\bar p\to\pi\pi$ or $p\bar p\to\gamma\gamma$. The problem here is that we cannot use the usual chiral theory because the energy transfer is of the same order of the cutoff $\Lambda\sim 1 \text{Gev}$.

In almost all the articles I have found those cross sections are derived by experimental observation, do you know possibles way to derive them theoretically? Or can you suggest me an article or review about that?

Comment: The non-perturbative regime in QCD is *hard*, but there is a huge range of literature on the matter in various approximations and effective theories. People have been hacking away at that problem for circa 40 years at this point, which makes for a bit much to but in the a Stack Exchange answer. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Can you suggest me any review or article where these kind of issue are treated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is non-perturbative QCD, so at low energy you cannot do much more than phenomenology or use experimental data. Both of the processes are somewhat rare. There is a lot of energy available, and the mean number of produced pions is 5 or 6, even at threshold (data like this can be found in the Particle Data Group tables).

At high energy these processes are exclusive reactions that can be studied using perturbative QCD. This is easier for $\bar{p}p\to\gamma\gamma$, which can be expressed (I think) in terms of a single non-perturbative parameter (so the energy dependence is predicted, and the parameter can be related to other processes), see http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.24.1808. Work that extends this formalism to somewhat lower energies can be found in http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0206288.